# What does “a day of the son of man” look like according to Luke 17:22

Tags: jesus, luke, son-of-man

> “And He said to the disciples, “The days will come when you will long to see **one of the days of the Son of Man**, and you will not see it.”
> ‭‭Luke‬ ‭17:22‬ ‭

What was Jesus referring to, that the disciples would long to see and how will that differ from the days of the son of man in the future if there is indeed a difference.

Example

> “And just as it happened in the days of Noah, **so it will be also in the days of the Son of Man**:”
> ‭‭Luke‬ ‭17:26‬ ‭

Answer (score 2):

I think the contrast between the "current" days of the son of man which the disciples will long for - with the future days of the son of man (which Jesus describes as similar to the days of Noah) - is explained in the prophecy Jesus reads about his ministry from Isaiah 61:1-2 in Luke 4:18

> "The Spirit of the Lord is on me, because he has anointed me to
> proclaim good news to the poor. He has sent me to proclaim freedom for
> the prisoners and recovery of sight for the blind, to set the
> oppressed free and proclaim the year of the Lord's favor"

This speaks of the "Year of the Lord's Favor" (Jubilee) which Jesus says is now fulfilled in his reading the scripture. A normal Jubilee [(as described in Leviticus)](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Leviticus%2025:8-55&version=ESV) occurs after a period of seven cycles of shmita (Sabbatical years) So 7 × 7 years. It involves the forgiveness of all debts, slaves being set free and an outporing of Gods favor and grace on the people. Most christians believe the period of Jesus Ministriy to be a kind of "Super Jubilee" that was prophecised in the [490 weeks prophecy in Daniel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prophecy_of_Seventy_Weeks) (instead of 7 x 7 years it was the culmination of a period of 70 X 7 years).

But the interesting thing is in Luke 4:18 when Jesus reads from the scroll of Isaiah he stops abruptly in the middle of reading Isaiah 61 verse 2. Where he stops reading is literally "mid verse". The rest of the verse 2 continues as:

> "and the day of vengeance of our God"

So here we see that Jesus has a kind of duel role. To first proclaim the year of God's favor. A period of immense grace and an outpouring of Gods forgiveness and healing. This is what he is doing and fulfilling in his earthly ministry where he pours out healing and miracles and sacrifices himself on behalf of the people. Thats why he only reads up to that section of the scroll which is describing the Year of the lords favor. But Jesus is also charged with proclaiming a day of vengeance. A day of God's wrath that will follow and he speaks about this as a "future" event a number of times.  (eg Matthew 24:30). This is when those who did not respond to the period of grace and call to repentance will be punished / destroyed. What is commonly called  in scripture **["The day of the Lord"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Day_of_the_Lord)**

This is expressed in many places in the Gospels - such as Mat 3:7 and Luke 3:7 where John the baptist see's pharisees coming to receive the Baptism of repentance and asks

> "who warned you to flee from the coming wrath"

Most believe the "Day of the lord" - the wrath and judgement Jesus, John and the disciples spoke of occured in 70AD during the [Roman Siege of Jerusalem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Siege_of_Jerusalem_(70_CE)). that began 3 days before Passover. Most of Israel had descended on the capital for the Passover celebration - the city was surrounded by the Roman army and eventually breached, the temple burnt to the ground (Matt 24:2) and most of the Jewish population killed and the remnant taken captive. This event which followed Jesus essentially put to an end Israel as a sovereign state for approximately 1900 years.

Luke 19:42

> As Jesus approached Jerusalem and saw the city, He wept over it and
> said, “If only you had known on this day what would bring you peace!
> But now it is hidden from your eyes. For the days will come upon you
> when your enemies will barricade you and surround you and hem you in
> on every side. They will level you to the ground—you and the children
> within your walls. They will not leave one stone on another, because
> you did not recognize the time of your visitation from God.

Answer (score 1):

This chapter is eschatological. But one key difference between Luke’s account  and Matthew’s account - commonly ‘lumped’ into what theologians label as the Olivet Discourse, is that Matthew’s account is describing the end days, where as Luke’s gospel is mostly describing days in the *not* so distant future, days that (many of) the audience would experience - although relating the events in the very near future, to, or rather as a ‘shadow’ of those end times.

Jesus was initially talking to the Pharisees. The sons of darkness, who will *miss* the signs leading up to those days. They were questioning him about the *coming* Kingdom…

> **LUKE 17:20** *Now when He was asked by the Pharisees when the kingdom of God would come*

… and *that* context lead Jesus to turn to his disciples, to finish that conversation, to ones who would listen and take note!

> **LUKE 17:22** *Then He said to the disciples, “The days will come when you will desire to see one of the days of the Son of Man, and you will not see it.*

Now, to the *context* or *meaning* of …”*you will desire to see one of the days of the Son of Man, and you will not see it.*” - we need to read on ….

> **LUKE 17:29** *but on the day that Lot went out of Sodom it rained fire and brimstone from heaven and destroyed them all.*

So *here* is the context, that in the ‘end times’ after a time of ‘all is well’, suddenly events will get so catastrophic - as in Sodom, that you would *wish* for the ‘son of man’ - as it is him, and only him, that is, by accepting Jesus as Messiah- that could have prevented this.

But although this does also reference the ‘end times’, it is *also* speaking or *foreshadowing* the destruction of Jerusalem in 70AD, and then the failed rebellion lead by Bar Kokhba.

Answer (score 0):

#### What does “a day of the son of man” look like according to Luke 17:22?

The book **Jesus—The Way, the Truth, the Life** under the chapter "[The Son of Man Will Be Revealed](https://wol.jw.org/en/wol/d/r1/lp-e/1102014693#h=8)" mentions the following:

> Jesus is indicating that the reign of the Son of man in the Kingdom is to be in the future. Before that time arrives, some disciples might anxiously look for it, but they will have to continue waiting until it is God’s appointed time for the Son of man to come.

[Ellicott's Commentary for English Readers](https://biblehub.com/commentaries/ellicott/luke/17.htm) expounds further on this thought:

> The words express both the backward glance of regret, and the forward look of yearning expectation. The former feeling had been described before, when the disciples were told that the children of the bride-chamber should fast when the Bridegroom should be taken from them ([Luke 5:34](https://biblehub.com/luke/5-34.htm); [Matthew 9:15](https://biblehub.com/matthew/9-15.htm); [Mark 2:19](https://biblehub.com/mark/2-19.htm)). The latter was expressed by-one of those who were now listening, when he spoke of men as “looking for and eagerly hasting” the coming of the day of God ([2Peter 3:12](https://biblehub.com/2_peter/3-12.htm)); by another, when he recorded the cry of the souls beneath the altar, “How long, O Lord?” ([Revelation 6:10](https://biblehub.com/revelation/6-10.htm)). It is, we must remember, the disciples, and not the Pharisees, who are now addressed. In the long, weary years of conflict that lay before them, they would often wish that they could be back again in the pleasant days of friendly converse in the old Galilean life, or that they could be carried forward to the day of the final victory. Analogous emotions of both kinds have, of course, been felt by the successors of the disciples in all ages of the Church. They ask, Why the former days were better than the latter? ([Ecclesiastes 7:10](https://biblehub.com/ecclesiastes/7-10.htm)); they ask also, in half-murmuring impatience, “Why tarry the wheels of His chariots?” ([Judges 5:28](https://biblehub.com/judges/5-28.htm)); sometimes, even in the accents of unbelief, “Where is the promise of His coming?” ([2Peter 3:4](https://biblehub.com/2_peter/3-4.htm)).

Additional insight can be seen from the parallel account in Matthew 24. In verse 37, Jesus is referring to his *parousía* (παρουσία Strong's [G3952](https://biblehub.com/greek/3952.htm)), presence or coming:

> For the coming of the Son of Man will be just like the days of Noah. (NASB)

So both Luke 17:22 and 26 are speaking about the same "days" which is Jesus second coming.